# Volley StringRequest Post works only on android 2.3.6

Tags: android, android-volley

evry thing gets posted fine on my phone 2.3.6 but on 4.0.1 and lolipop and marshmallo and nothing being posted althought im sure all params are filled, more comment in the code to explain further. could it be because I'm useing try..finally inside the volley response try? as I said there is no problem on android 2.3.6 that is what made me crazy

```
    private void pub(//final strings for params) {
    String tag_string_req = "pubb";
    String url = "http://.....";
    rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    donutprogress.setProgress(12);//this thing works on UI
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                donutprogress.setProgress(donutprogress.getProgress() + 43);
                JSONObject adimg = jObj.getJSONObject("somthing");
                final Number adId = ((Number) adimg.get("id"));
                //String responsemessage = jObj.getString("message");
                //progress.setText(responsemessage);
                try {
               //some stuf after posting pot not the cause of problem it is not posting in first place
                } finally {
                    Thread t5 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Activitythis.this,
                                        Activitymain.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t5.start();
                    try {
                        t5.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response) {
            pub(//params strings);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("title", tite);
            //other params............
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            return params;
        }

    };
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Comment: whats your logcat are saying?

Comment: For sorry I cant use it. very old computer and cant plug my device to it. but on catlog app on 2.3.6 there was nothing wrong